# Can we install OpenSSH 8.4 on ubuntu 16.04 or does it cause compatibility issues? CVE-2020-14145 CVE-2020-15778

Tags: 16.04, openssh

We received OpenSSH Information Disclosure Vulnerability CVE-2020-14145 CVE-2020-15778 on some of our ubuntu 16.04 and ubuntu 18.04 Servers and the fix recommended is to upgrade to OpenSSH 8.4/8.4P1

But the current version of OpenSSH is 7.6 on all 16.04 and 18.04 servers.

So please check and suggest if openssh8.4 would be compatible to be installed on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What CVE/security issue are you worried about?   Ubuntu doesn't upgrade versions for older systems unless it's less work than backport-ing the secuirity fixes to the existing version.   You can view the updated fixes for the *bionic* package via https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh_7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3/changelog  (do the same for *xenial* if you prefer)   You can look up CVE fixes and see if patches are available too if you look

Comment: @guiverc CVE-2020-14145 CVE-2020-15778

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 didn't get patches as wasn't impacted by either, the *bionic* wasn't deemed worthy as only impacts legacy devices using an old protocol (which its suggested to not use anyway), check yourself via https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-14145.html https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2020/CVE-2020-15778.html

Comment: guiverc So what do you suggest ? Should we or Should we not upgrade/install OpenSSH 8.4 on ubuntu 16.04 (OR) should we just leave OpenSSH at the current version 7.6 ?